# How to implement Bilateral Filter on Kinect?

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

I am starting from an example in the Kinect SDK example KinectBridgeWithOpenCVBasics-D2D for Visual Studio 2013.

In the program which allows users to select different kinds of OpenCV filtering on the Color and Depth streams of Kinect, the selection is implemented using a switch statement.  As I want to add bilateral filtering to the program, I tried adding to the switch statement like this:

```
case IDM_COLOR_FILTER_CANNYEDGE:
    {
        const double minThreshold = 30.0;
        const double maxThreshold = 50.0;

        // Convert image to grayscale for edge detection
        cvtColor(*pImg, *pImg, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
        // Remove noise
        blur(*pImg, *pImg, Size(3,3));
        // Find edges in image
        Canny(*pImg, *pImg, minThreshold, maxThreshold);
        // Convert back to color for output
        cvtColor(*pImg, *pImg, CV_GRAY2RGBA);
    }
    break;
case IDM_COLOR_FILTER_BILATERAL:
    {
        // Apply Bilateral Filter
        Mat dest;
        bilateralFilter(*pImg, dest, 5, 80, 80);
    }
    break;
```

It didn't work.  An exception was thrown and the output displays

```
First-chance exception at 0x770BC42D in KinectVision.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0A49E4E4.
Unhandled exception at 0x770BC42D in KinectVision.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0A49E4E4.
```

Anybody kind enough to point out where I went wrong please?

--- added 3/8/2015

I had previously done a program to do the bilateral filter on a single image.  This works and the code is below.

```
Mat image;
Mat dest;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
bilateralFilter(image, dest, 5, 50, 3);
```

The difference between this program and the Kinect is single image vs 30fps streaming.

Comment: I don't use OpenCV much, but just by looking at your code and the documentation of the function, it seems like your `Mat dest` should be allocated to the same size as `pImg` *before* you call `bilateralFilter` (that is, do `Mat dest = pImg->clone()`)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.  I tried both the copy and clone methods but it didn't work (same exception).  The reason why I left it this way is because I have this in another program (added above) that just does the bilateral filtering on a single image and the code works.

Comment: please avoid *pointers* to cv::Mat

Comment: expanding on @berak point, `pImg` should probably not be a pointer....that should be an instance of `cv::Mat`.

Comment: *pImg is a pointer to an array parameter for the function that holds the switch statement.  The Canny detector routine works fine with the *pImg and so too do three other filters not shown above.  In the OpenCV documentation, the Canny Edge detector is expressed as "C++: void Canny(InputArray image, OutputArray edges, double threshold1, double threshold2, int apertureSize=3, bool L2gradient=false )" and the Bilateral Filter as "C++: void bilateralFilter(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int d, double sigmaColor, double sigmaSpace, int".  So the InputArray's are called in the same manner (?)